# Game of Thrones Recipe help

Tags: all-grain, recipe, extract-plus-grains

I have the Unofficial Game of Thrones Cookbook and it has some beer recipes I'm currently trying to follow. However, I'm confused as to wether it has two sets of instructions or all the brews are a mix of grain and extract?
The recipes look like this

```
Malt/Grain/Sugar
6.0 pounds Wheat Malt
4.0 pounds Pilsner Malt

Extract (for 6 pounds of Wheat Malt and 4 pounds of Pilsner Malt)
8.0 pounds Wheat Liquid Malt Extract (LME)
```

Is that two different options, one for all-grain, one for extract brewing, or is it a mixed recipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its two different options. You can either do the malt version or the extract version. Wheat Liquid Malt Extract is actually a mix (usually 50/50) of wheat malt and pils/2-row/pale malt, depending on the manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, assuming this is for a 20 liter / 5 gallon batch, 10 pounds of malt sounds about right. No clue about the amount of extract.